# Display json data in gridview in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, gridview

I have been created simple shopify app to retrieve product details.

When i access code from gihub.

It run successfully and display product details in text box.

I need to simple change to show the product details in grid view.

Here is dafault.aspx:

existing code;

default.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" codefile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleWebApplication._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="APIOutput" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my output screenshot http://s22.postimg.org/xj9zacxa9/untitled.jpg

I need to display product details in gridview,

default.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using ShopifyAPIAdapterLibrary;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace SampleWebApplication
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShopifyAuthorizationState state = HttpContext.Current.Session["Shopify.AuthState"] as ShopifyAuthorizationState;
            ShopifyAPIClient client
                = new ShopifyAPIClient(state);
            APIOutput.Text = (string)client.Get("/admin/products.json");
        }
    }
}
```

but I just confused with codefile, Can anyone help me get the product details in gridview?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No need to use Gridview, direct create HTML table on serverside, or else you need to Convert JSON to datatable then bind it to your gridview

Comment: i just confused, how to use?.. can you help? thanks

Comment: Using JSON.net library you can easily convert your JOSN to Datatable

Answer (score 0):

Using [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) you can convert your JSON string to DataTable.

First you need to add JSON.net DLL (http://json.codeplex.com/) in your project. Then add its namespace in your Webpage.

Now DerializeDataTable will return datatable, you need to replace string json variable with your SHOPIfY json result;

```
public DataTable DerializeDataTable()
{
    const string json = @"[{""Name"":""AAA"",""Age"":""22"",""Job"":""PPP""},"
                       + @"{""Name"":""BBB"",""Age"":""25"",""Job"":""QQQ""},"
                       + @"{""Name"":""CCC"",""Age"":""38"",""Job"":""RRR""}]";
    var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<datatable>(json);
    return table;
}
```

---

Code to bind GridView:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
         gvBind(); //Bind gridview
     }
}

public void gvBind()
{   
     var myTable=DerializeDataTable()
     gvproducts.DataSource = myTable;
     gvproducts.DataBind();
}
```

---

Edited:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShopifyAuthorizationState state = HttpContext.Current.Session["Shopify.AuthState"] as ShopifyAuthorizationState;
        ShopifyAPIClient client
            = new ShopifyAPIClient(state);
        var myJsonString = (string)client.Get("/admin/products.json");
        var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<datatable>(myJsonString );
        gvproducts.DataSource = table ;
        gvproducts.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: wIthout  knowledge of your JSON result i can't explain more

Comment: actually i have authorize.aspx.. when i run authorize.aspx, i put store name in the text box and submit.. then it will show product details in text box in the default.aspx url,,

Comment: i understood your edited answer.. but what is first script?,, can you guide me.. thanks

Comment: @pcs: First script is the sample code for converting dummy JSON string to DataTable. If my answer helps you, do the Upvote. If you got any other solution, then pls do post here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add reference to json service from visual studio. Then you will have proper classes for your json data, which you can easily parse for yours TextBox.

Comment: Do you get data from any kind of service ? If so right click your project -> Add -> Service Reference. Then type service url. VS will create proxy for your service and generate classes for service data.